# Android Studio ListView Item Favorite ImageButton Features

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, togglebutton

Android Studio ListView Item Favorite ImageButton Features

Hi guys,

Please help me.

I have listview item with heart ImageButton. (@drawable/heart)

I want to change the (@drawable/heart) into (@drawable/heartred) after i click the click.

It means it is mark as favorite.

I also want to display those item with red heart in my favorite tab.

below is the image and code.

[image]

**fragment_fragment_one.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.magicstarme.virtualsongbook.FragmentOne">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <!--<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment_one" />-->

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/slListView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="This is tab 2" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="This is tab 3" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</FrameLayout>
```

**fragment_fragment_one_slview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="3
        ">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/artist"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/volume"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right|top"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/relativeLayout3">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/mic"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:src="@drawable/mic"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:background="#ffffff" />


        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="#cccccc">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**FragmentOne.class**

```
package com.magicstarme.virtualsongbook;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link FragmentOne.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link FragmentOne#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public FragmentOne() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentOne.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FragmentOne newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentOne fragment = new FragmentOne();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    public static boolean heart_selected = false;

    public static int position = -1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);

        TabHost host = (TabHost) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        host.setup();

        //Tab 1
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("SONG LIST");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        spec.setIndicator("SONG LIST");
        host.addTab(spec);

            ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults> slResults = GetSearchResults();
        final ListView sllv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.slListView);
        sllv.setAdapter(new FragmentOne_Adapter(getActivity(), slResults));

        //Tab 2
        spec = host.newTabSpec("NEW SONGS");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        spec.setIndicator("NEW SONGS");
        host.addTab(spec);

        //Tab 3
        spec = host.newTabSpec("FAVORITES");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        spec.setIndicator("FAVORITES");
        host.addTab(spec);

        return rootView;
    }

    //SONG LIST
    private ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults> GetSearchResults(){
        ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults> results = new ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults>();

        FragmentOne_slResults slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("1");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 1 Song Title 1 Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 1");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 1");
        slr.setNumber("1");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("2");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2 Song Title 2 Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
        slr.setNumber("2");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("3");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 3");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
        slr.setNumber("3");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("4");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
        slr.setNumber("4");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("5");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2 Song Title 2 Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
        slr.setNumber("5");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("6");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
        slr.setNumber("6");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("7");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2 Song Title 2 Title 2 Song Title 2 Song Title 2 Title 23 tle 2 Song Title 2 Song Title 2 Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
        slr.setNumber("7");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("8");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
        slr.setNumber("8");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("9");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 3");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
        slr.setNumber("9");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("10");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
        slr.setNumber("10");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("11");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 3");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
        slr.setNumber("11");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("12");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
        slr.setNumber("12");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("13");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 3");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
        slr.setNumber("13");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("14");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
        slr.setNumber("14");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setId("15");
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 3");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
        slr.setNumber("15");
        results.add(slr);


        return results;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

**FragmentOne_Adapter.class**

```
 package com.magicstarme.virtualsongbook;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.Image;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Joe on 6/29/2016.
 */
public class FragmentOne_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults> oneslArrayList;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private boolean[] isFavorite;

    public FragmentOne_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults> slresults) {
        oneslArrayList = slresults;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return oneslArrayList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return oneslArrayList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one_slview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.txtArtist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist);
            holder.txtVolume = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.volume);
            holder.txtNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number);

            holder.buttonHeart = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.heart);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtTitle.setText(oneslArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.txtArtist.setText(oneslArrayList.get(position).getArtist());
        holder.txtVolume.setText(oneslArrayList.get(position).getVolume());
        holder.txtNumber.setText(oneslArrayList.get(position).getNumber());

        if (oneslArrayList.get(position).isFavorite) {
            holder.buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heartred);
        }
        holder.buttonHeart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Toggle the favorites status of the imageButton and the data.
                boolean isFavorite = !oneslArrayList.get(position).isFavorite;
                oneslArrayList.get(position).setIsFavorite(isFavorite);
                holder.buttonHeart.setImageResource(isFavorite ? R.drawable.heartred : R.drawable.heart);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtArtist;
        TextView txtVolume;
        TextView txtNumber;
        ImageButton buttonHeart;
        ToggleButton btnFavorite;
        ImageView btnHeart;
    }
}
```

**FragmentOne_Result.class**

package com.magicstarme.virtualsongbook;

```
/**
 * Created by Joe on 6/29/2016.
 */
public class FragmentOne_slResults{
    private String id = "";
    private String title = "";
    private String artist = "";
    private String volume = "";
    private String number = "";
    boolean isFavorite;

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getTitle() {return title;}

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }
    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setVolume(String volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }
    public String getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {this.number = number;}
    public String getNumber() {return number;}

    public void setIsFavorite(boolean isFavorite) {this.isFavorite = isFavorite;}
    //public String getFavorite() {return favorite;}
}
```

Comment: im trying to develop an app like this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.platinumkaraoke.digitalsongbook&hl=en     is this app use database? or everything is static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Instead of imagebutton use Toggle for favourite

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/tgbFav"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:background="@drawable/fav_checked"
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn=""/>
```

fav_checked.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/heart"
    android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/heartred"
    android:state_checked="false"
    />
```

for favourite list to display once toggle is clicked update the database or flag this item as favourite so you can list all the favourite item .. Hope this helps you

inside your adaptor

```
[ur fav toggle].setChecked(favorites[position]);
    [ur fav toggle].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Boolean fav;
            if (favorites[position] == true) {
                favorites[position] = false;
            } else {
                favorites[position] = true;
            }
        }
    });
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one_slview, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.txtArtist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist);
        holder.txtVolume = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.volume);
        holder.txtNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number);

        holder.buttonHeart = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.heart);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtTitle.setText(oneslArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.txtArtist.setText(oneslArrayList.get(position).getArtist());
    holder.txtVolume.setText(oneslArrayList.get(position).getVolume());
    holder.txtNumber.setText(oneslArrayList.get(position).getNumber());

        holder.buttonHeart.setChecked(oneslArrayList.get(position).isFavorite);
    holder.buttonHeart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boolean isFavorite = !oneslArrayList.get(position).isFavorite;
            oneslArrayList.get(position).setIsFavorite(isFavorite);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

i have updated getView of adaptor
Now make a database with insert,fetch and update(for favourite) functionality. Then in FragmentOne_slResults class initialize `boolean isFavorite=false`. 
So in this class add these items in databse

```
//SONG LIST
private ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults> GetSearchResults(){
    ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults> results = new ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults>();

    FragmentOne_slResults slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
    slr.setId("1");
    slr.setTitle("Song Title 1 Song Title 1 Title 2");
    slr.setArtist("Artist 1");
    slr.setVolume("Vol 1");
    slr.setNumber("1");
    results.add(slr);

    slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
    slr.setId("2");
    slr.setTitle("Song Title 2 Song Title 2 Title 2");
    slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
    slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
    slr.setNumber("2");
    results.add(slr);

    slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
    slr.setId("3");
    slr.setTitle("Song Title 3");
    slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
    slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
    slr.setNumber("3");
    results.add(slr);

    slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
    slr.setId("4");
    slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
    slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
    slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
    slr.setNumber("4");
    results.add(slr);

    slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
    slr.setId("5");
    slr.setTitle("Song Title 2 Song Title 2 Title 2");
    slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
    slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
    slr.setNumber("5");
    results.add(slr);

    slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
    slr.setId("6");
    slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
    slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
    slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
    slr.setNumber("6");
    results.add(slr);

    slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
    slr.setId("7");
    slr.setTitle("Song Title 2 Song Title 2 Title 2 Song Title 2 Song Title 2 Title 23 tle 2 Song Title 2 Song Title 2 Title 2");
    slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
    slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
    slr.setNumber("7");
    results.add(slr);

    slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
    slr.setId("8");
    slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
    slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
    slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
    slr.setNumber("8");
    results.add(slr);

    slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
    slr.setId("9");
    slr.setTitle("Song Title 3");
    slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
    slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
    slr.setNumber("9");
    results.add(slr);

    slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
    slr.setId("10");
    slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
    slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
    slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
    slr.setNumber("10");
    results.add(slr);

    slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
    slr.setId("11");
    slr.setTitle("Song Title 3");
    slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
    slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
    slr.setNumber("11");
    results.add(slr);

    slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
    slr.setId("12");
    slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
    slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
    slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
    slr.setNumber("12");
    results.add(slr);

    slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
    slr.setId("13");
    slr.setTitle("Song Title 3");
    slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
    slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
    slr.setNumber("13");
    results.add(slr);

    slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
    slr.setId("14");
    slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
    slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
    slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
    slr.setNumber("14");
    results.add(slr);

    slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
    slr.setId("15");
    slr.setTitle("Song Title 3");
    slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
    slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
    slr.setNumber("15");
    results.add(slr);

    //add results into the database
    return results;
}
```

so now instead of this 
            `ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults> slResults = GetSearchResults();` replace this with `ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults> slResultsFromDb=[fetch data from database];
        ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults> slResults=new ArrayList<>();
        if(slResultsFromDb.size>0){
            slResults.addAll(slResultsFromDb);
        }else
                slResults.addAll(GetSearchResults());` update database on favourite onclick Hope this works for you

Comment: please see update. i now use togglebutton. but when i click one item, some of the item will turn to red too. then when i scroll it change. also when i refresh the redheart is removed.

Comment: wow it works. but i got new problem. when i click sidebar and click other fragment. the favorite mark will remove, i want so stay the favorite mark and also display those item in favorite tab. thanks.

Comment: Yeah it will be removed because your favourite data is not persistent. So u need to update it in ur local or remote database so specific favourite item will be flaged. I think you should update your database,since all your data in listview are static.

Comment: sorry im just new to android. how can i do that without connecting to internet? because i want my app to run offline.. like this application.. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.platinumkaraoke.digitalsongbook&hl=en

Comment: GetSearchResults() you should store it in database or something. So check database if it is empty create the data else fetch it from database.

Comment: hi @arjun, i update my code again.. can you please help me. i now use database.. please help..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a boolean to your `FragmentOne_slResults` class which will keep track of whether the object is favorited or not. Don't forget to add a setter and a getter for that boolean (isFavorite() and setFavorite(boolean)).

At that point you will have to check the value of that boolean in the `getView()` method so you can change the background image of the ImageButton based on whether it is favorited or not. To get the image to change when you tap it you should also add an `OnClickListener` to each heart ImageButton in your adapter's `getView()` method which will update the the favorited status of the data at that position and change the background image of the image button. Your getView() method will look like:

```
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one_slview, null);
      holder = new ViewHolder();

      holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
      holder.txtArtist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist);
      holder.txtVolume = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.volume);
      holder.txtNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number);

      holder.buttonHeart = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.heart);
      final ImageButton tmp = holder.buttonHeart;

      holder.btnHeart = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.heart);

      convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
      holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtTitle.setText(oneslArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.txtArtist.setText(oneslArrayList.get(position).getArtist());
    holder.txtVolume.setText(oneslArrayList.get(position).getVolume());
    holder.txtNumber.setText(oneslArrayList.get(position).getNumber());
    // Set the correct heart status based on the favorite status.
    holder.buttonHeart.setImageResource(oneslArrayList.get(position).isFavorite 
         ? R.drawable.hearted : R.drawable.heart);
    holder.buttonHeart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        // Toggle the favorites status of the imageButton and the data.
        boolean isFavorite = !oneslArrayList.get(position).isFavorite();
        oneslArrayList.get(position).setFavorite(isFavorite);
        holder.buttonHeart.setImageResource(isFavorite ? R.drawable.hearted : R.drawable.heart);
      }
    }

    return convertView;
  }
```

Your class called `FragmentOne_slResults` should look like:

```
/**
 * Created by Joe on 6/29/2016.
 */
public class FragmentOne_slResults{
    private String id = "";
    private String title = "";
    private String artist = "";
    private String volume = "";
    private String number = "";
    // this is now private
    private boolean isFavorite;

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getTitle() {return title;}

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }
    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setVolume(String volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }
    public String getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {this.number = number;}
    public String getNumber() {return number;}

    public void setIsFavorite(boolean isFavorite) {this.isFavorite = isFavorite;}
    // The return type of this is boolean, not String
    public boolean isFavorite() {return isFavorite;}
}
```

Also, to clean up your code see if you can get rid of all the calls to `oneslArrayList.get(position)` and just get the item in one variable and reuse that.

Comment: where .isFavorite came from? im getting error in this part. sorry im new to android. thanks.

Comment: You need to add that to your model object for `FragmentOne_slResults` I mentioned this in the first sentence of my post but Ill go back and make it more explicit. Without that data your objects wont persist their "favorited status" and if you redraw the list the hearted images will be lost.

Comment: @Joehamir It seems like you have a lot of people helping you out already and I am about to hit the sack. Let me know if things don't work out and I'd be happy to try and help resolve the issues you are having.

Comment: i add this private Boolean isFavorite; and this  public void setFavorite(boolean isFavorite) {this.isFavorite = isFavorite;} in my result but still not working.. im getting the error isFavorite has private access.

Comment: please i need more help. it change now but the problem is when i click the first item, the other item will change to.. and when i scroll it change again..

Comment: I'll be available at 9 pm est tonight. If you are on stackoverflow then we can get on chat and work on this.

Comment: Join me in chat here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116527/discussion-between-dr-nitpick-and-joehamir

Comment: Ahh I see you added your up to date code. Ill just edit that and update my answer.

Comment: I have updated the code @Joehamir. There were 2 changes I made. 1) I added the getter for isFavorite, please make sure that you use the function `isFavorite()` instead of trying to access the field `isFavorite` in your adapter class (I am using the function in my code. 2) The reason the heart was appearing for other list items was because we were improperly setting the drawable in the `getView()` method. I have corrected that now by using a ternary operator.

Comment: hi @Dr. Nitpick, i update my code again.. can you please help me. i now use database.. please help..

Comment: You are going to have to add methods to your db adapter to edit the favorite column and you will need to make your own subclass of `SimpleCursorAdapter` where you override `bindView` and `newView` to add the click listener logic to your heart image. This type of change to your architecture/question really warrants making a new question. I would have recommended getting your previous approach to work and then trying to enhance that to use a db in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

1> you are add favorite songs status in your  bean or model class like below

```
    FragmentOne_slResults slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
    slr.setId("1");
    slr.setTitle("Song Title 1 Song Title 1 Title 2");
    slr.setArtist("Artist 1");
    slr.setVolume("Vol 1");
    slr.setNumber("1");
    slr.setIsFavorite(false);//add this variable in your model class
    results.add(slr);
```

2> when you are select item for favorite then update this value with true value and notify your adapter 
3> add below code for check condition of song isFavorite or not

```
    if (oneslArrayList.get(position).isFavorite) {
    holder.buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_heart);
   }else{
   holder.buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.white__heart);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

imho, Instead `reinventing the wheel` you could use Like Button library from these list:

1. [Like Button](https://github.com/jd-alexander/LikeButton)
2. [LikeAnimation](https://github.com/frogermcs/LikeAnimation), only work from API >= 21.
3. [SmallBang](https://github.com/hanks-zyh/SmallBang)